# Changing mouse color in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cursor, mouse, dos

I'm doing sort of a paint in assembly, and I want the user to choose the color he wants to draw with, so I want the mouse to change its color according to the color the user is using right now.

How can I do it without creating my own mouse?
Can `int 33h` help me here?

Comment: What operating system? What platform?

Comment: Operating system is Dos,  by platform do you mean assembler? if so then TASM...

Comment: With platform I mean ISA. So for DOS, you probably target 8086 or 80386.

Comment: I have added tags to more closely reflect what you want.

Comment: ty fuz and yes the platform is the classic 8086

Comment: You'll need to set the graphics cursor yourself using INT 33h, AX=0009h

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
MyFirstBlock:
mov ah, 09h ; Bored stuff...
mov cx, 80h ; 80h covers only the text and 1000h the entire remain screen
mov al, 20h ; More bored stuff...
mov bl, 4fh ; This is the color, try with CMD, Ex. 00 is black-black.
int 10h ; Call VGA to display block
```

and then, call it with `call MyFirstBlock`, this is the code for display a single block, use you print function:

```
mov si, MyEmptyText
call YouFunctionThatPrintTTYCharacters

MyEmptyText: db ' ', 0
```

Entire Code:

```
MyFirstBlock:
mov ah, 09h ; Bored stuff...
mov cx, 80h ; 80h covers only the text and 1000h the entire remain screen
mov al, 20h ; More bored stuff...
mov bl, 4fh ; This is the color, try with CMD, Ex. 00 is black-black.
int 10h ; Call VGA to display block
; call MyFirstBlock is useless so dont put it!, until you are in a diferent file...
mov si, MyEmptyText
call YouFunctionThatPrintTTYCharacters

MyEmptyText: db ' ', 0

%INCLUDE "SomeBasicFunctions.asm"
```

i wait that this will be an answer for your question.

Oh and int 33h i think that he only works in MS-DOS, or not?, i never used it, instead i use this.